# Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, optimization, href

The following are two methods of building a link that has the sole purpose of running JavaScript code. Which is better, in terms of functionality, page load speed, validation purposes, etc.?

```js
function myJsFunc() {
    alert("myJsFunc");
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

or

```js
function myJsFunc() {
    alert("myJsFunc");
}
```

```html
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

Comment: Why use a link when you want a button? Then there is no issue with pseudo–protocols.

Comment: Neither. If you really *must* use a link, then use a span styled as a link. No href to bother about. And why `void(0)` when `void 0` will do?

Answer (score 2311):

I use `javascript:void(0)`.

Three reasons. Encouraging the use of `#` amongst a team of developers inevitably leads to some using the return value of the function called like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    //Some code
    return false;
}
```

But then they forget to use `return doSomething()` in the onclick and just use `doSomething()`.

A second reason for avoiding `#` is that the final `return false;` will not execute if the called function throws an error. Hence the developers have to also remember to handle any error appropriately in the called function.

A third reason is that there are cases where the `onclick` event property is assigned dynamically.  I prefer to be able to call a function or assign it dynamically without having to code the function specifically for one method of attachment or another. Hence my `onclick` (or on anything) in HTML markup look like this:

```
onclick="someFunc.call(this)"
```

OR

```
onclick="someFunc.apply(this, arguments)"
```

Using `javascript:void(0)` avoids all of the above headaches, and I haven't found any examples of a downside.

So if you're a lone developer then you can clearly make your own choice, but if you work as a team you have to either state:

Use `href="#"`, make sure `onclick` always contains `return false;` at the end, that any called function does not throw an error and if you attach a function dynamically to the `onclick` property make sure that as well as not throwing an error it returns `false`.

OR

Use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

The second is clearly much easier to communicate.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2013: `javascript:void(0)` violates [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/CSP) on CSP-enabled HTTPS pages. One option would be then to use `href='#'` and `event.preventDefault()` in the handler, but I don't like this much. Perhaps you can establish a convention to use `href='#void'` and make sure no element on the page has `id="void"`. That way, clicking a link to non-existing anchor will not scroll the page.

Comment: You can use "#" and then bind a click event to all links with "#" as the `href`. This would be done in jQuery with: `$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false; });`

Comment: `#void` would add an entry to the browser history nonetheless. Another way would be to use the URL of a resource that returns HTTP status 204 (and still use `preventDefault` - the 204 is just a fallback).

Comment: @Nathan Non-jquery: `const voidLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"') for (const voidLink of voidLinks) { voidLink.addEventListener('click', e => { e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false }) voidLink.addEventListener('keypress', e => { if (e.keyCode === 13) e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false }) }`
That is including event listener on keypress Enter (code 13) for people navigation through page with keyboard.

Comment: @s3c The enter keypress already triggers the click event, so is that last listener necessary?

Comment: @Nathan Did not know that. Thank you. PS: Can't find documentation on it, but from what I've found from other people it seem confirmed. Fixed snippet: `const voidLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"') for (const voidLink of voidLinks) { voidLink.addEventListener('click', e => { e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false }) }`

Comment: I've been trying to find why I was getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'` error in the debug log. It kept pointing to my `href` in my navigation menu. I checked functions, css, anything I could think of and then thanks to Google brought me to this page. Changing `href="javascript:void()"` to href="javascript:void(0)"` and now no more error in the debug. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @HPWD This is [cargo cult programming](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). [`void`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-void-operator) is an _operator_, not a function. It’s `void 0`; the parentheses in `void(0)` don’t do anything. `void()` is just as invalid as, say, `return ();`. `()` is not a valid UnaryExpression.

Comment: @SebastianSimon—I was going to say that… but you did it for me. :-)

Comment: I was wondering why anyone would use parenthesis if they aren't needed at all and found an answer in [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void#description). They can be useful when determining the order of resolution of the expression: `void 2 === "2"; // (void 2) === '2', returns false`, whereas `void (2 === "2"); // void (2 === '2'), returns undefined`. Not that that makes `void(0)` any less equal than `void 0`, but the former may have (had) the `0` as a placeholder for future javascript code (discouraged as mentioned above and below).

Answer (score 1415):

Neither.

If you can have an actual URL that makes sense use that as the HREF.  The onclick won't fire if someone middle-clicks on your link to open a new tab or if they have JavaScript disabled.

If that is not possible, then you should at least inject the anchor tag into the document with JavaScript and the appropriate click event handlers.

I realize this isn't always possible, but in my opinion it should be striven for in developing any public website.

Check out *[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)* and *[Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)* (both Wikipedia).

Comment: _“If that is not possible, then” use a button instead._ That’s how this answer should’ve ended.

Comment: and if we use a button, how would our lovely users will open their href in new tab using their shiny smartphones?

Comment: @mohamedtebry—you've missed the point of the question: "*building a link that has the sole purpose of running JavaScript code*". The issue is using a link as a button, there is no href to open.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Bootstrap dropdowns have anchor structure for styling. Sometimes it is necessary to use anchor https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#single-button

Answer (score 809):

Doing `<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` or `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` or whatever else that contains an `onclick` attribute - was okay back five years ago, though now it can be a bad practice. Here's why:

1. It promotes the practice of obtrusive JavaScript - which has turned out to be difficult to maintain and difficult to scale. More on this in *[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)*.
2. You're spending your time writing incredibly overly verbose code - which has very little (if any) benefit to your codebase.
3. There are now better, easier, and more maintainable and scalable ways of accomplishing the desired result.

### The unobtrusive JavaScript way

Just don't have a `href` attribute at all! Any good CSS reset would take care of the missing default cursor style, so that is a non-issue. Then attach your JavaScript functionality using graceful and unobtrusive  best practices - which are more maintainable as your JavaScript logic stays in JavaScript, instead of in your markup - which is essential when you start developing large scale JavaScript applications which require your logic to be split up into blackboxed components and templates. More on this in *[Large-scale JavaScript Application Architecture](http://speakerdeck.com/u/addyosmani/p/large-scale-javascript-application-architecture)*

### Simple code example

```js
// Cancel click event
$('.cancel-action').click(function(){
    alert('Cancel action occurs!');
});

// Hover shim for Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7.
$(document.body).on('hover','a',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
a { cursor: pointer; color: blue; }
a:hover,a.hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cancel-action">Cancel this action</a>
```

### A blackboxed *[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)* example

For a scalable, blackboxed, Backbone.js component example - *[see this working jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/balupton/sTzdD/)*. Notice how we utilize unobtrusive JavaScript practices, and in a tiny amount of code have a component that can be repeated across the page multiple times without side-effects or conflicts between the different component instances. Amazing!

### Notes

- Omitting the `href` attribute on the `a` element will cause the element to not be accessible using `tab` key navigation. If you wish for those elements to be accessible via the `tab` key, you can set the `tabindex` attribute, or use `button` elements instead. You can easily style button elements to look like normal links as mentioned in *[Tracker1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8525002/130638)*.
- Omitting the `href` attribute on the `a` element will cause [Internet Explorer 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) and [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) to not take on the `a:hover` styling, which is why we have added a simple JavaScript shim to accomplish this via `a.hover` instead. Which is perfectly okay, as if you don't have a href attribute and no graceful degradation then your link won't work anyway - and you'll have bigger issues to worry about.
- If you want your action to still work with JavaScript disabled, then using an `a` element with a `href` attribute that goes to some URL that will perform the action manually instead of via an Ajax request or whatever should be the way to go. If you are doing this, then you want to ensure you do an `event.preventDefault()` on your click call to make sure when the button is clicked it does not follow the link. This option is called graceful degradation.

Comment: And what about passing a parameter tot he final JS method? Is it possible?

Answer (score 358):

`'#'` will take the user back to the top of the page, so I usually go with `void(0)`.

`javascript:;` also behaves like `javascript:void(0);`

Comment: The way to avoid that is to return false in the onclick event handler.

Comment: Returning false in the event handler doesn't avoid that if JavaScript the JS doesn't run successfully.

Comment: using "#someNonExistantAnchorName" works well because it has nowhere to jump to.

Comment: If you have a base href, then `#` or `#something` will take you to that anchor *on the base href* page, instead of on the current page.

Comment: Any use of `#` or `void(0)` is bad practice and shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: The shebang (`#!`) does the trick but it's definitely bad practice.

Comment: @Neel, any anchor that doesn't actually exist in the document (e.g. `#_`) does the same trick, with the same drawbacks.

Answer (score 352):

I would honestly suggest neither.  I would use a stylized `<button></button>` for that behavior.

```css
button.link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>A button that looks like a <button type="button" class="link">link</button>.</p>
```

This way you can assign your onclick.  I also suggest binding via script, not using the `onclick` attribute on the element tag.  The only gotcha is the psuedo 3d text effect in older IEs that cannot be disabled.

---

If you *MUST* use an A element, use `javascript:void(0);` for reasons already mentioned.

- Will always intercept in case your onclick event fails.
- Will not have errant load calls happen, or trigger other events based on a hash change
- The hash tag can cause unexpected behavior if the click falls through (onclick throws), avoid it unless it's an appropriate fall-through behavior, and you want to change the navigation history.

NOTE: You can replace the `0` with a string such as `javascript:void('Delete record 123')` which can serve as an extra indicator that will show what the click will actually do.

Comment: This answer should be up top. If you are having this dilemma, chances are you are actually in need of a `button`. And IE9 is quickly losing market shares, fortunately, and the 1px active effect should not prevent us to use semantic markup. `<a>` is a link, it's meant to send you somewhere, for actions we have `<button>`'s.

Comment: If the action in the onclick will act as a link (navigate to other page or open something in new window) then it should be semantically be an `<a>` tag. If the action is some in-page popup or some other functionality on same page, it should be  a `<button>`.

Answer (score 152):

The first one, ideally with a real link to follow in case the user has JavaScript disabled. Just make sure to return false to prevent the click event from firing if the JavaScript executes.

```
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc(); return false;">Link</a>
```

If you use Angular2, this way works:

`<a [routerLink]="" (click)="passTheSalt()">Click me</a>`.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465728/2803344

Comment: So in user agents with JavaScript enabled and the function supported this run a JavaScript function, falling back (for user agents where the JS fails for whatever reason) to a link to the top of the page? This is rarely a sensible fallback.

Comment: "ideally with a real link to follow in case the user has JavaScript disabled", it should be going to a useful page not #, even if it's just an explanation that the site needs JS to work. as for failing, I would expect the developer to use proper browser feature detection, etc before deploying.

Answer (score 110):

Neither if you ask me;

If your "link" has the sole purpose of running some JavaScript code it doesn't qualify as a link; rather a piece of text with a JavaScript function coupled to it. I would recommend to use a `<span>` tag with an `onclick handler` attached to it and some basic CSS to immitate a link. Links are made for navigation, and if your JavaScript code isn't for navigation it should not be an `<a>` tag.

Example:

```js
function callFunction() { console.log("function called"); }
```

```css
.jsAction {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #00f;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p>I want to call a JavaScript function <span class="jsAction" onclick="callFunction();">here</span>.</p>
```

Comment: This approach restricts the 'link' to a mouse only operation.  An anchor can be visited via the keyboard and its 'onclick' event is fired when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: Hardcoding colors in your CSS would prevent the browser from using custom colors the user may define, which can be a problem with accessibility.

Comment: `<span>`s are not meant to *do* anything. `<A>`nchors and `<buttons>` are used for that!

Comment: Using `buttons` is a better choice here while using a `span` is not.

Comment: _“Links are made for navigation, and if your JavaScript code isn't for navigation it should not be an `<a>` tag.”_ — Even if the JavaScript code is “for navigation”, a link may not be appropriate every time.

Answer (score 107):

Ideally you'd do this:

```
<a href="javascriptlessDestination.html" onclick="myJSFunc(); return false;">Link text</a>
```

Or, even better, you'd have the default action link in the HTML, and you'd add the onclick event to the element unobtrusively via JavaScript after the DOM renders, thus ensuring that if JavaScript is not present/utilized you don't have useless event handlers riddling your code and potentially obfuscating (or at least distracting from) your actual content.

Answer (score 78):

Using just `#` makes some funny movements, so I would recommend to use `#self` if you would like to save on typing efforts of `JavaScript bla, bla,`.

Comment: For reference, `#self` doesn't appear to be special.  Any fragment identifier that doesn't match the name or id of any element in the document (and isn't blank or "top") should have the same effect.

Comment: has the same effect, as cHao said. You just need to return false on element `a` when clicked (`onclick`)

Answer (score 72):

I use the following

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>
```

instead

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>
```

Comment: `href="javascript:"` and `href="javascript:void 0;"` are all equivalent as well, but they’re all equally bad.

Comment: This answer offers no justification whatsoever. Bald assertions aren't helpful.

Answer (score 71):

I recommend using a `<button>` element instead, *especially* if the control is supposed to produce a change in the data. (Something like a POST.)

It's even better if you inject the elements unobtrusively, a type of progressive enhancement. (See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0#134957).)

Comment: this depend if you need button on your bem ( block element model) of html.

Answer (score 59):

I agree with suggestions elsewhere stating that you should use regular URL in `href` attribute, then call some JavaScript function in onclick. The flaw is, that they automaticaly add `return false` after the call.

The problem with this approach is, that if the function will not work or if there will be any problem, the link will become unclickable. Onclick event will always return `false`, so the normal URL will not be called.

There's very simple solution. Let function return `true` if it works correctly. Then use the returned value to determine if the click should be cancelled or not:

**JavaScript**

```
function doSomething() {
    alert( 'you clicked on the link' );
    return true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="path/to/some/url" onclick="return !doSomething();">link text</a>
```

---

Note, that I negate the result of the `doSomething()` function. If it works, it will return `true`, so it will be negated (`false`) and the `path/to/some/URL` will not be called. If the function will return `false` (for example, the browser doesn't support something used within the function or anything else goes wrong), it is negated to `true` and the `path/to/some/URL` is called.

Answer (score 54):

`#` is better than `javascript:anything`, but the following is even better:

HTML:

```
<a href="/gracefully/degrading/url/with/same/functionality.ext" class="some-selector">For great justice</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".some-selector").click(myJsFunc);
});
```

You should always strive for graceful degradation (in the event that the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled...and when it is with specs. and budget).  Also, it is considered bad form to use JavaScript attributes and protocol directly in HTML.

Comment: @Muhd: Return should activate `click` on links…

Answer (score 46):

Unless you're writing out the link using JavaScript (so that you know it's enabled in the browser), you should ideally be providing a proper link for people who are browsing with JavaScript disabled and then prevent the default action of the link in your onclick event handler. This way those with JavaScript enabled will run the function and those with JavaScript disabled will jump to an appropriate page (or location within the same page) rather than just clicking on the link and having nothing happen.

Answer (score 39):

Definitely hash (`#`) is better because in JavaScript it is a pseudoscheme:

1. pollutes history
2. instantiates new copy of engine
3. runs in global scope and doesn't respect event system.

Of course "#" with an onclick handler which prevents default action is [much] better. Moreover, a link that has the sole purpose to run JavaScript is not really "a link" unless you are sending user to some sensible anchor on the page (just # will send to top) when something goes wrong. You can simply simulate look and feel of link with stylesheet and forget about href at all.

In addition, regarding cowgod's suggestion, particularly this: `...href="javascript_required.html" onclick="...` This is good approach, but it doesn't distinguish between "JavaScript disabled" and "onclick fails" scenarios.

Answer (score 32):

I usually go for

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="yourFunction()">Link description</a>
```

It's shorter than javascript:void(0) and does the same.

Answer (score 29):

I choose use `javascript:void(0)`, because use this could prevent right click to open the content menu. But `javascript:;` is shorter and does the same thing.

Answer (score 28):

I would use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();return false;">Link</a>
```

**Reasons:**

1. This makes the `href` simple, search engines need it. If you use anything else ( such as a string), it may cause a `404 not found` error.
2. When mouse hovers over the link, it doesn't show that it is a script.
3. By using `return false;`, the page doesn't jump to the top or break the `back` button.

Comment: i dont agree with "1." cause it gives error when u put ur script link when scripts are not allowed. so that kind of links should be added with the js code. that way people can avoid those links while script is not allowed and see no errors at all.

Answer (score 25):

**Don't use links for the sole purpose of running JavaScript.**

The use of href="#" scrolls the page to the top; the use of void(0) creates navigational problems within the browser.

Instead, use an element other than a link:

```
<span onclick="myJsFunc()" class="funcActuator">myJsFunc</span>
```

And style it with CSS:

```
.funcActuator { 
  cursor: default;
}

.funcActuator:hover { 
  color: #900;
}
```

Comment: Use a button, not a span. Buttons naturally fall in the focus order so can be accessed without a mouse / trackpad / etc.

Comment: Adding ton Quentin's comment: as currently written, keyboard users won't reach the `span` element because it is a non-focusable element. That's why you need a button.

Comment: You can make it focusable by adding `tabindex="0"` to the span. That said, using button is better because it gives you the desired functionality for free. To make it accessible using a span you not only need to attach a click handler, but a keyboard event handler that looks for presses of space bar or enter key and then fires the normal click handler. You would also want to change the second CSS selector to `.funcActuator:hover, .funcActuator:focus` so the fact that the element has focus is apparent.

Answer (score 24):

So, when you are doing some JavaScript things with an `<a />` tag and if you put `href="#"` as well, you can add **return false** at the end of the event *(in case of inline event binding)* like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc(); return false;">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

*Or you can change the **href** attribute with JavaScript like:*

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

**or**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

---

But semantically, all the above ways to achieve this are wrong *(it works fine though)*. If any element is not created to navigate the page and that have some JavaScript things associated with it, then it should not be a `<a>` tag.

You can simply use a `<button />` instead to do things or any other element like b, span or whatever fits there as per your need, because you are allowed to add events on all the elements.

---

So, **there is one benefit** to use `<a href="#">`. You get the cursor pointer by default on that element when you do `a href="#"`. For that, I think you can use CSS for this like `cursor:pointer;` which solves this problem also.

And at the end, if you are binding the event from the JavaScript code itself, there you can do `event.preventDefault()` to achieve this if you are using `<a>` tag, but if you are not using a `<a>` tag for this, there you get an advantage, you don't need to do this.

So, if you see, it's better not to use a tag for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 22):

Usually, you should always have a fallback link to make sure that clients with JavaScript disabled still have some functionality. This concept is called unobtrusive JavaScript.

Example... Let's say you have the following search link:

```
<a href="search.php" id="searchLink">Search</a>
```

You can always do the following:

```
var link = document.getElementById('searchLink');

link.onclick = function() {
    try {
        // Do Stuff Here        
    } finally {
        return false;
    }
};
```

That way, people with JavaScript disabled are directed to `search.php` while your viewers with JavaScript view your enhanced functionality.

Answer (score 22):

It would be better to use jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").css("cursor", "pointer");
});
```

and omit both `href="#"` and `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

The anchor tag markup will be like

```
<a onclick="hello()">Hello</a>
```

Simple enough!

Comment: This is what I was going to say.  If a link has a fallback url that makes sense, use that.  Otherwise, just omit the href or use something more semantically appropriate than an <a>.  If the only reason everyone is advocating including the href is to get the finger on hover, a simple "a { cursor: pointer; }" will do the trick.

Comment: May I say this is the option that SO decided to go with. Check the "flag" links, for instance.

Comment: That gives terrible accessibility. Try it in SO: you can't flag a post without using the mouse. The "link" and "edit" links are accessible by tabbing, but "flag" isn't.

Comment: I agree with this option. If the anchor has no purpose other than JavaScript, it shouldn't have a href.  @Fatih: Using jQuery means that if JavaScript is disabled, the link will NOT have a pointer.

Comment: If you are going to go this route, why not bind the click using jQuery as well?  Part of the great thing about using jQuery is the ability to seperate your javascript from your markup.

Comment: Better to add a `js` class to the body, and Let CSS handle the CSS. `body.js a{cursor: pointer;}`

Answer (score 19):

If you happen to be using [**AngularJS**](http://angularjs.org/), you can use the following:

```
<a href="">Do some fancy JavaScript</a>
```

Which will not do anything.

In addition

- It will not take you to the top of the page, as with (#)

  - Therefore, you don't need to explicitly return `false` with JavaScript
- It is short an concise

Comment: But this would cause the page to reload, and since we're always using javascript to modify the page, this is unacceptable.

Comment: @HenryHu I figured out that the reason it did not reload was because of AngularJS. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you could forget the onclick and just use the href:

```
<a href="javascript:myJsFunc()">Link Text</a>
```

It gets around the need to return false. I don't like the `#` option because, as mentioned, it will take the user to the top of the page. If you have somewhere else to send the user if they don't have JavaScript enabled (which is rare where I work, but a very good idea), then Steve's proposed method works great.

```
<a href="javascriptlessDestination.html" onclick="myJSFunc(); return false;">Link text</a>
```

Lastly, you can use `javascript:void(0)` if you do not want anyone to go anywhere and if you don't want to call a JavaScript function. It works great if you have an image you want a mouseover event to happen with, but there's not anything for the user to click on.

Comment: The only downside with this (from memory, I may be wrong) is that IE doesn't consider an A to be an A if you don't have a href inside it. (So CSS rules won't work)

Answer (score 17):

I believe you are presenting a false dichotomy. These are not the only two options.

I agree with Mr. D4V360 who suggested that, even though you are using the anchor tag, you do not truly have an anchor here. All you have is a special section of a document that should behave slightly differently. A `<span>` tag is far more appropriate.

Comment: Also if you were to replace an `a` with a `span`, you'll need to remember to make it focusable via keyboard.

Comment: No, a span should not be used. There's an element specifically for things that are clickable but not links, and that is `<button>`.

Answer (score 16):

I personally use them in combination. For example:

HTML

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

---

with little bit of jQuery

```
$('a[href="#"]').attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
```

or

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

But I'm using that just for preventing the page jumping to the top when the user clicks on an empty anchor. I'm rarely using onClick and other `on` events directly in HTML.

My suggestion would be to use `<span>` element with the `class` attribute instead of
an anchor. For example:

```
<span class="link">Link</span>
```

---

Then assign the function to `.link` with a script wrapped in the body and just before the `</body>` tag or in an external JavaScript document.

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $('.link').click(function() {
            // do something
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

***Note:** For dynamically created elements, use:

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

And for dynamically created elements which are created with dynamically created elements, use:

```
$(document).on('click','.link', function() {
    // do something
});
```

---

Then you can style the span element to look like an anchor with a little CSS:

```
.link {
    color: #0000ee;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.link:active {
    color: red;
}
```

Here's **[a jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/mdesdev/Dn8YT/)** example of above aforementioned.

Answer (score 16):

I tried both in google chrome with the developer tools, and the `id="#"` took 0.32 seconds. While the `javascript:void(0)` method took only 0.18 seconds. So in google chrome, `javascript:void(0)` works better and faster.

Comment: Actually they don't do the same. # makes you jump to top of the page.

Answer (score 15):

When I've got several faux-links, I prefer to give them a class of 'no-link'.

Then in jQuery, I add the following code:

```
$(function(){
   $('.no-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

And for the HTML, the link is simply

```
<a href="/" class="no-link">Faux-Link</a>
```

I don't like using Hash-Tags unless they're used for anchors, and I only do the above when I've got more than two faux-links, otherwise I go with javascript:void(0).

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="no-link">Faux-Link</a>
```

Typically, I like to just avoid using a link at all and just wrap something around in a span and use that as a way to active some JavaScript code, like a pop-up or a content-reveal.

Answer (score 15):

On a modern website the use of href should be avoided if the element is only doing JavaScript functionality (not a real link).

Why?
The presence of this element tells the browser that this is a link with a destination. 
With that, the browser will show the Open In New Tab / Window function (also triggered when you use shift+click). 
Doing so will result in opening the same page without the desired function triggered (resulting in user frustration).

In regards to IE:
As of IE8,  element styling (including hover) works if the doctype is set. Other versions of IE are not really to worry about anymore.

Only Drawback:
Removing HREF removes the tabindex.
To overcome this, you can use a button that's styled as a link or add a tabindex attribute using JS.

Answer (score 14):

It's nice to have your site be accessible by users with JavaScript disabled, in which case the href points to a page that performs the same action as the JavaScript being executed. Otherwise I use "**#**" with a "`return false;`" to prevent the default action (scroll to top of the page) as others have mentioned.

Googling for "`javascript:void(0)`" provides a lot of information on this topic. Some of them, like [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20090210041609/http://blog.reindel.com/2006/08/11/a-hrefjavascriptvoid0-avoid-the-void/) mention reasons to **NOT use void(0)**.

Comment: The blog entry does not cite the reference as to why javascript:void(0) should be avoided.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken now.

Comment: Not good solution for accessibility: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.0/href-no-hash

Comment: `javascript:void(0);` is also not good if you want to use a strict Content Security Policy that disables inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 13):

I'm basically paraphrasing from [this practical article using progressive enhancement](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx). **The short answer is that you never use `javascript:void(0);` or `#` unless your user interface has already inferred that JavaScript is enabled, in which case you should use `javascript:void(0);`**. Also, do not use span as links, since that is semantically false to begin with.

Using [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) friendly URL routes in your application, such as /Home/Action/Parameters is a good practice as well. If you have a link to a page that works without JavaScript first, you can enhance the experience afterward. Use a real link to a working page, then add an onlick event to enhance the presentation.

Here is a sample. Home/ChangePicture is a working link to a form on a page complete with user interface and standard HTML submit buttons, but it looks nicer injected into a modal dialog with jQueryUI buttons. Either way works, depending on the browser, which satisfies mobile first development.

```
<p><a href="Home/ChangePicture" onclick="return ChangePicture_onClick();" title="Change Picture">Change Picture</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangePicture_onClick() {
        $.get('Home/ChangePicture',
              function (htmlResult) {
                  $("#ModalViewDiv").remove(); //Prevent duplicate dialogs
                  $("#modalContainer").append(htmlResult);
                  $("#ModalViewDiv").dialog({
                      width: 400,
                      modal: true,
                      buttons: {
                          "Upload": function () {
                              if(!ValidateUpload()) return false;
                              $("#ModalViewDiv").find("form").submit();
                          },
                          Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                      },
                      close: function () { }
                  });
              }
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In term of SEO I would prefer this way. Using as many friendly URL shall definitely improve page value factor.

Answer (score 11):

Don't lose sight of the fact that your URL may be necessary -- onclick is fired before the reference is followed, so sometimes you will need to process something clientside before navigating off the page.

Answer (score 11):

You can also write a hint in an anchor like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void('open popup image')" onclick="return f()">...</a>
```

so the user will know what this link does.

Answer (score 10):

There is one more important thing to remember here. [Section 508](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_508_Amendment_to_the_Rehabilitation_Act_of_1973) compliance.
Because of it, I feel it's necessary to point out that you need the anchor tag for screen readers such as [JAWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAWS_%28screen_reader%29) to be able to focus it through tabbing. So the solution "just use JavaScript and forget the anchor to begin with" is not an option for some of this. Firing the JavaScript inside the href is only necessary if you can't afford for the screen to jump back up to the top. You can use a settimeout for 0 seconds and have JavaScript fire to where you need focus but even the apage will jump to the top and then back.

Answer (score 9):

Just to pick up the point some of the other have mentioned.

It's much better to bind the event 'onload'a or $('document').ready{}; then to put JavaScript directly into the click event.

In the case that JavaScript isn't available, I would use a href to the current URL, and perhaps an anchor to the position of the link. The page is still be usable for the people without JavaScript those who have won't notice any difference.

As I have it to hand, here is some jQuery which might help:

```
var [functionName] = function() {
   // do something
};

jQuery("[link id or other selector]").bind("click", [functionName]);
```

Comment: LowPro is really nice for unobtrusive JS if you have a lot of complex behaviors.

Answer (score 9):

I use href="#" for links that I want a dummy behaviour for. Then I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href='#']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Meaning if the href equals to a hash (*="#") it prevents the default link behaviour, thus still allowing you to write functionality for it, and it doesn't affect anchor clicks.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say the best way is to make an href anchor to an ID you'd never use, like #Do1Not2Use3This4Id5 or a similar ID, that you are 100% sure no one will use and won't offend people.

1. `Javascript:void(0)` is a bad idea and violates Content Security Policy on CSP-enabled HTTPS pages https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/CSP (thanks to @jakub.g)
2. Using just `#` will have the user jump back to the top when pressed
3. Won't ruin the page if JavaScript isn't enabled (unless you have JavaScript  detecting code
4. If JavaScript is enabled you can disable the default event
5. You have to use href unless you know how to prevent your browser from selecting some text, (don't know if using 4 will remove the thing that stops the browser from selecting text)

Basically no one mentioned 5 in this article which I think is important as your site comes off as unprofessional if it suddenly starts selecting things around the link.

Answer (score 9):

The most simple and used by everyone mostly is **javascript:void(0)** You can use it instead of using **#** to stop  **tag redirect to header section**.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="testFunction();">Click To check Function</a>

function testFunction() {
    alert("hello world");
}
```

Comment: if use versión that require detect javascript and use function for dectect browser version you can instead using #
```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="testFunction();">Click to check </a>

function testFunction() {
   alert("hello, world")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Ideally you should have a real URL as fallback for non-JavaScript users.

If this doesn't make sense, use `#` as the `href` attribute.  I don't like using the `onclick` attribute since it embeds JavaScript directly in the HTML.  A better idea would be to use an external JS file and then add the event handler to that link.  You can then prevent the default event so that the URL doesn't change to append the `#` after the user clicks it.

Answer (score 8):

What I understand from your words is that you want to create a link just to run JavaScript code.

Then you should consider that there are people who blocks JavaScript out there in their browsers.

So if you are really going to use that link only for running a JavaScript function then you should add it dynamically so it won't be even seen if the users didn't enable their JavaScript in the browser and you are using that link just to trigger a JavaScript function which makes no sense to use a link like that when JavaScript is disabled in the browser.

For that reason neither of them is good when JavaScript is disabled.

Aand if JavaScript is enabled and you only want to use that link to invoke a JavaScript function then

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>
```

is far better way than using

```
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>
```

because href="#" is going to cause the page to do actions that are not needed.

Also, another reason why `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` is better than `<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` is that JavaScript is used as the default scripting language for most of the browsers. As an example Internet Explorer, uses an onclick attribute to define the type of scripting language that would be used. Unless another good scripting language pops up, JavaScript will be used by Internet Explorer as the default too, but if another scripting language used `javascript:`, it would let Internet Explorer to understand which scripting language is being used.

Considering this, I would prefer using and exercising on

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>
```

enough to make it a habit and to be more user friendly please add that kind of links within the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".blabla").append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>')
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I see a lot of answers by people who want to keep using `#` values for `href`, hence, here is an answer hopefully satisfying both camps:

**A)** I'm happy to have `javascript:void(0)` as my `href` value:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="someFunc.call(this)">Link Text</a>
```

**B)** I am using jQuery, and want `#` as my `href` value:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunc.call(this)">Link Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Stop page jumping when javascript links are clicked.
       Only select links where the href value is a #. */
    $('a[href="#"]').live("click", function(e) {
         return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
         e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    });
</script>
```

Note, if you know links won't be created dynamically, use the `click` function instead:

`$('a[href="#"]').click(function(e) {`

Answer (score 8):

Why not using this? This doesn't scroll page up.

```
<span role="button" onclick="myJsFunc();">Run JavaScript Code</span>
```

Comment: This actually seems like a very good solution, thanks. I've replaced `href="#"` with `role="button"` everywhere and then stuck `*[role="button"] { cursor:pointer; }` in the CSS and that seems to work very well without the need for unnecessary JS :)

Comment: As others have said, this cannot be activated using the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, when pressing TAB key one cannot navigate to it. Using `tabindex="0"` might make it better but I'm not sure it that's appropriate solution

Comment: 5 years after the answer I also consider the a11y features:)

Comment: @HrvojeGolcic Please note the [accessibility concerns](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#accessibility_concerns) when using `tabindex`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Agree! I'd absolutely not recommend it. Better is `<a>`! In this specific case I guess since he is already implementing `role` then it's a custom control. Indeed he needs `tabindex`, events for SPACE and ENTER keys, visible focus etc.

Comment: Why not `<button>`? Seems silly to use a span and then have to use ARIA to make it semantically a button when `<button>` exists.

Answer (score 8):

## Edited on 2019 January

In **HTML5**, using an a element without an href attribute is **valid**. It is considered to be a **"placeholder hyperlink"**

> If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents.

Example:

```
<a>previous</a>
```

If after that you want to do otherwise :

1 - If your link doesn't go anywhere, don't use an `<a>` element. Use a `<span>` or something else appropriate and add CSS `:hover` to style it as you wish.

2 - Use the `javascript:void(0)` OR `javascript:undefined` OR `javascript:;` if you want to be raw, precise and fast.

Answer (score 7):

**If** you use a link as a way to **just** execute some JavaScript code (instead of using a span like D4V360 greatly suggested), just do:

```
<a href="javascript:(function()%7Balert(%22test%22)%3B%7D)()%3B">test</a>
```

If you're using a link with onclick for navigation, don't use href="#" as the fallback when JavaScript is off. It's usually very annoying when the user clicks on the link. Instead, provide the same link the onclick handler would provide if possible. If you can't do that, skip the onclick and just use a JavaScript URI in the href.

Comment: This would give an error if JS was off instead of seemingly doing nothing or just go to the top of the page

Comment: @mplungjan If JS is off, clicking it will do nothing, which makes sense if there's no non-js alternative representation/action of what the JS is doing. Having the href be "#" or some URI isn't any more useful, in the case I was describing.

Comment: So have href="jsdisabled.html" instead

Comment: @mplungjan You could. But, that navigates away from the page.

Comment: @mplungjan Understood. You could do that. No argument there. I'd personally just have a "this page requires JS" message for the page that disappears when JS is on though.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an `<a>` element, just use this:

```
<a href="javascript:myJSFunc();" />myLink</a>
```

Personally I'd attach an event handler with JavaScript later on instead (using `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` or maybe <put your favorite JavaScript framework here > also).

Comment: Can someone explain the reason why this answer has so many downvotes?

Comment: This answer has man downvotes because (as noted in the other response) putting javascript in the actual tag is considered very bad practice.  Click handlers should never be in the HTML itself.

The top answer best explains this in detail.

Answer (score 7):

In total agreement with the overall sentiment, use `void(0)` when you need it, and use a valid URL when you need it.

Using [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) you can make URLs that not only do what you want to do with JavaScript disabled, but also tell you exactly what its going to do.

```
<a href="./Readable/Text/URL/Pointing/To/Server-Side/Script" id="theLinkId">WhyClickHere</a>
```

On the server side, you just have to parse the URL and query string and do what you want. If you are clever, you can allow the server side script to respond to both Ajax and standard requests differently. Allowing you to have concise centralized code that handles all the links on your page.

[URL rewriting tutorials](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/)

Pros

- Shows up in status bar
- Easily upgraded to Ajax via onclick handler in JavaScript
- Practically comments itself
- Keeps your directories from becoming littered with single use HTML files

Cons

- Should still use event.preventDefault() in JavaScript
- Fairly complex path handling and URL parsing on the server side.

I am sure there are tons more cons out there. Feel free to discuss them.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the href and remove all links that have only hashes:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="run_foo()"> foo </a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         // on DOM ready or some other event

   $('a[href=#]').attr('href','');    // set all reference handles to blank strings
                                      //  for anchors that have only hashes

});
```

Comment: This is bad, particularly in IE (up to version 10, not sure about 11). Clicking a link with an empty href results in an unnecessary (and probably unwanted) request being fired, and in IE, it attempts to open Windows Explorer.

Comment: @squidbe: This was an old answer but I think that depends on how your JS is written.  If you didn't want that to fire, I think you would `onclick="return run_foo()"` and have run_foo return `false` or just add a `return false` line after the function is called.  The point of this answer was that you could remove href tags when JS is enabled.  The ideal solution would be to populate the href with a fail-safe link most likely to a server-side rendered page `href="render/full_page.script?arg=value" onclick="loadAJAXContent.call(this); return false"`

Comment: You are correct about the fail-safe solution. My point was that the href attribute value is not intended to ever be an empty string, and setting it to empty can cause unwanted side effects. Even when you return false, if there are errors in your script, the undesired request and undesired Windows behavior still occur. If the option is between leaving the hash in the href and removing it via script, I think it's better to leave it.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly prefer to keep my JavaScript out of my HTML markup as much as possible. If I'm using `<a>` as click event handlers then I'd recommend using `<a class="trigger" href="#">Click me!</a>`.

```
$('.trigger').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff...
});
```

It's very important to note that many developers out there believe that using anchor tags for click-event handlers isn't good. They'd prefer you to use a `<span>` or `<div>` with some CSS that adds `cursor: pointer;` to it. This is a matter if much debate.

Answer (score 6):

You **should not use** inline `onclick="something();"` in your HTML to not polluate it with meaningless code; all click bindings must be set in Javascript files (*.js).

Set binding like this : `$('#myAnchor').click(function(){... **return false**;});`  or  `$('#myAnchor').bind('click', function(){... **return false**;});`

Then you have a clean HTML file easy to load (and seo friendly) without thousands of `href="javascript:void(0);"` and just `href="#"`

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of what to do with `href`. if you don't have an `href` attribute on an `a` tag, it won't appear as a clickable link.

Comment: But what if there is a list of elements and I want add link to remove some element from it by string ID?

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript:void(0) here instead of using # to stop anchor tag redirect to header section.

```
function helloFunction() {
    alert("hello world");
}
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="helloFunction();">Call Hello Function</a>
```

Comment: If one uses the '#' and does not wish the redirect, one simply needs to ensure that whatever onclick behavior being triggered by the event returns false as its final return value. This will prevent the navigation after the click event has finished bubbling. It can even be something sillly, like onclick="return console.log('I am a worthless link!')" (the console log evaluates to undefined, which yields a falsey value). void(0) is simply an old school syntax for getting a true undefined response.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually **four options** here.

Using `return false;` allows you to keep the anchor version in cases where you want a safe "fallback" in browsers that have **JavaScript *disabled* or it is not supported in the user agent** (1-5% of user's now). You can use the anchor "#" sign, an empty string, or a special URL for the `href` **should your script fail**. Note that you must use an `href` so screen readers know it is a hyperlink. (Note: I am not going to get into arguments about removing the `href` attribute as that point is moot here. Without an `href` on an anchor means the anchor is no longer a hyperlink and just an html tag with a click event on it that is captured.)

```
<a href="" onclick="alert('hello world!');return false;">My Link</a>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hello world!');return false;">My Link</a>
<a href="MyFallbackURL.html" onclick="alert('hello world!');return false;">My Link</a>
```

Below is the more popular design today using `javascript:void(0)` inside the `href` attribute. If a browser doesn't support scripting it should post again back to its page again, as an empty string is returned for the `href` hyperlink path. Use this if you don't care who supports JavaScript.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('hello world!');">My Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more option for completeness sake, that prevents the link from doing anything even if JavaScript is disabled, and it's short :)

```
<a href="#void" onclick="myJsFunc()">Run JavaScript function</a>
```

If the id is not on the page, the link will do nothing.

Generally, I agree with Aaron Wagner's answer, the JavaScript link should be injected with JavaScript code into the document.

Comment: In HTML5, most of the restrictions on IDs are lifted, so they can start with a number. The only restrictions now are that they must be unique and cannot contain spaces. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute. Also, your solution modifies the URL and inserts a history entry, polluting the back button with useless states.

Comment: @AndyE yep, your right, I wasn't aware that id's could start with numbers, also this solution was never meant to be any good or recommended, I added it for "completeness sake" on the number of ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

• `Javascript: void(0);` is void to null value **[Not assigned]**, which means your browser is going to `NULL` click to **DOM**, and the window return to false.
• The `'#'` does not follow the DOM or Window in javascript. which that mean the '#' sign inside anchor href is a **LINK**. Link to the same current direction.

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:void(0)` will deprecate in future, therefore you should use `#`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Both approaches have no discernible effect on how quickly a website loads.

**Explanation:**
Well, Both are equally effective. The primary difference is related to click action. The first approach () will alter the URL in the address bar to "#,". The second method () will leave the URL in the address bar unchanged. Hence, both are good to go.

**Tip:** Use the second method as a best practice, that's: `(<a href="javascript:void(0)">)` as it is more valid HTML and doesn't affect the URL bar.

Answer (score -2):

Bootstrap modals from before 4.0 have a basically undocumented behavior that they will load `href`s from `a` elements using AJAX unless they are exactly `#`. If you are using Bootstrap 3, `javascript:void(0);` hrefs will cause javascript errors:

`AJAX Error: error GET javascript:void(0);`

In these cases you would need to upgrade to bootstrap 4 or change the href.